# TikZ rectangle single rounded corner

Tags: tikz-pgf, rounded-corners

How to round just one (or two, or three) corners of a TikZ rectangle?
I can only get none or all rounded!

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [fill=red, rounded corners] {Round north east corner};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```